# xcode - how to change compiler?

Tags: xcode, llvm-gcc

I am trying to change the compiler version in xcode 3.1.4. I went to Project settings -> Build -> Compiler version, but I can only choose "com.apple.compilers.llvmgcc42".

I looked up the library/xcode/plugins/-folder and it looks like there are several compiler versions installed. But I can't choose them in the project' settings?

---

Sadly, this doesn't help my problem with the compilers. Does anyone know why xcode doesn't show up any additional compiler versions, altough they seem to bee in the plugin list?
I already searched a lot, but it looks like all the tutorials are assuming, that the different compilers are already available in the build settings...

Comment: why do you want to change the compiler version? Also, why don't you upgrade your xcode to version 4?

Comment: When I try to use gcc4.2 to compile my phonegap-testproject, it throws several errors. After a lookup it looks like the iphone sdk doesn't support version 4.2. Also I can't use xcode 4, because it requires a later mac version. I am using Mac OSX 10.5.8.

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap already fixed your problem. See [changelog](http://www.phonegap.com/2011/04/28/phonegap-0-9-5-released/) of version 0.9.5. Please make sure you are using PhoneGap >=0.9.5

Comment: That is weird. I am currently using version 1.0 of Phonegap.

Comment: PhoneGap version 1.0 requires: Intel-based computer with Mac OS X Snow Leopard (10.6) http://www.phonegap.com/start#ios

Comment: Ok, I guess i got the stuff with "Leopard" and "Snow Leopard" mixed up. Why does the framework require Snow Leopard in particular?